# React performance on multiple component click handlers [single click handler vs click handler for each component]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I've got a component that renders a list of children elements, is there a performance difference between assigning a single click handler for all the items and getting info from the dataset attribute versus creating a function for each children and passing the data as an argument?
What's better or more idiomatic?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class UserList extends Component {
  deleteUser() {
    const user = JSON.parse(e.curentTarget.dataset['user']);
    // handle deletion
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.users.map((u) => (
          <li
            key={u.id}
            data-user={JSON.stringify(u)}
            onClick={::this.deleteUser} >
            delete {u.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

VS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class UserList extends Component {
  deleteUser(user) {
    // handle deletion
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.users.map((u) => (
          <li
            key={u.id}
            data-user={JSON.stringify(u)}
            onClick={() => this.deleteUser(u)} >
            delete {u.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know which one performs better, the best way to find out is by running the performance tests yourself.

As far as coding styling is concerned however, I strongly prefer the second option.

Remember that a core concept of React is one way data flow. You write to the DOM. You rarely read from it. (User input being the exception to the rule.) You should avoid writing to, and reading from, the DOM what you can keep in memory. In my opinion, using data attributes in this manner is an anti-pattern.

The fact that you have to serialize the object with JSON just makes it worse. JSON parsing/stringification has its own cost. Moreover, it obviously fails as a general use case, since what you pass to `deleteUser` is not the original object but a reconstructed object. This may be fine for your use case, but equally it could be a source of bugs.